# Spring Boot Devtools exposing the entire classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Today I noticed an unexpected behavior on the Spring Boot application I'm developing: if I type http://localhost:8080/application.properties on the browser, it happily downloads the file.

Upon further inspection, it looks like my entire classpath is exposed. I can download template files and even the compiled `.class` files by simply sending GET requests.

After commenting the dependencies of the project one by one, it seems like `spring-boot-devtools` is the one causing the problem since whenever it is removed, the application behaves as expected.

As far as I know, the features provided by Devtools are supposed to be disabled when you package the application and run it using `java -jar`, but even then the problem persists.

I downloaded a fresh project from http://start.spring.io/, containing nothing but the `web` and `devtools` dependencies and I was able to reproduce the problem, so I'm guessing that this is some expected behavior, even though I could not find it documented anywhere. Or maybe it is a bug on Devtools. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a question for stack overflow but should be reported as an issue with Spring Boot instead.

Comment: But the question is exactly whether this is something that should be reported as an issue (and according to punkrocker27ka's answer, it is) or correct behavior described in some obscure part of the Spring documentation. Do you have some suggestions on how to reword it in order to make it acceptable? Or is it definitely off-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the dependency scope of `spring-boot-devtools` to `optional`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  <scope>optional</scope>
</dependency>
```

The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools) does indicate that when running the app with java -jar that devtools will be automatically disabled, which it appears not to be doing.  It further explains that you can scope this dependency as optional to prevent it from being transitively applied.  That does the trick.

**Update**:

This was confirmed to be a regression in Spring Boot 1.4.3.RELEASE.  See the [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7880) for more detail. The fix is currently targeted for 1.5.0.